# Создать приложение для работы с изображениями

Tags: c#, изображения, .net

Всем привет.

Стоит задача создать windows приложение... Что должно получиться приблизительно: загружаем одно относительно большое изображение, сразу его показываем и получаем возможность нанести на него из списка доступных, заранее загруженых в приложение иконок, а-ля drag and drop, с возможностью их различных поворотов, масштабирования и т.п. После этого, естественно, сохранить исходное изображение на диск. )

Никогда с изображениями не работал, да и в общем в десктоп разработке имею мало опыта. Вот и даже не знаю, с какой стороны подойти к решению данной задачи, какие тулзы использовать. У кого какие советы будут? Или, может, что-то подобное уже есть реализовано? Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Тебе именно C#?

Comment: Мне именно под Windows,  это одно условие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе нужно Qt (http://qt-project.org/)

Читаешь, как все работает в целом, смотришь примеры: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-painting.html и http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview-diagramscene.html

Далее все зависит от твоей фантазии.

И да, вот прога, примерно которая тебе нужна, вроде на ++, не смотрел: http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/EasyPaint?content=140877